# Trying to formulate exclusive sql query from all-inclusive where clause

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Is it possible to calculate this sales report in one query? I'm not so hot with SQL and having trouble wrapping my head around joins considering the all-inclusive where clause.

TABLES (assume 1-N for foreign keys):

```
TABLE contacts
id

TABLE reservations
id
created_at
contact_id

TABLE reservation_trips
id
reservation_id -- never null
amount
quantity
trip_type_id -- never null

TABLE cost_adjustments
id
reservation_trip_id -- never null
cost_type_id -- never null

TABLE trip_types
id
title

TABLE cost_types
id
title
kind
```

EXAMPLE WHERE:

```
reservations.created_at >= '2013-01-01T09:00:00+00:00' AND
reservations.created_at < '2014-01-01T09:00:00+00:00' AND
reservation_trips.trip_type_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) AND
cost_adjustments.trip_type_id in (5, 6, 7, 8) AND
contact_id in (9, 10, 11, 12)
```

RESULT COLUMNS:

```
trip_types.title as trip_type_title,
COUNT(DISTINCT reservations.id) as bookings, -- distinct reservations
SUM(reservations.commissions) as commissions, -- distinct reservations
SUM(reservation_trips.id) as guests, -- distinct reservation_trips
SUM(reservation_trips.amount * reservation_trips.quantity) as gross_sales, -- distinct reservation_trips
SUM(cost_adjustments.amount * cost_adjustments.quantity) as adjustments, -- distinct cost_adjustments where cost_types.kind != 'tax'
SUM(gross_sales + adjustments - commissions) as net_sales
```

The table columns would look like this:

```
TRIP TYPE | BOOKINGS | GUESTS | GROSS SALES | ADJUSTMENTS | COMMISSIONS | NET SALES
```

Thanks!

Comment: if a reservation has two trips of different trip type, how should the commission be allocated to the different trip types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is to avoid counting the intermediate levels multiple times. One way to do it is do divide by the number of items at each level.

Another approach, which can be more efficient is to put each level in it's own subquery and then join them all up.

Here's an untested stab at the first method. It might need some `IsNull(xxx, 0)` fixup.

```
Select
    tt.title as trip_type_title,
    count(distinct r.id) as bookings,
    sum(r.commissions) / count(distinct r.id) as commissions,
    count(distinct rt.id) as guests, -- this seems odd, but it's in the example
    sum(rt.amount * rt.quantity) / count(distinct rt.id) as gross_sales,
    sum(ca.amount * ca.quantity) as adjustments,
    sum(rt.amount * rt.quantity) / count(distinct rt.id) + sum(r.commissions) / count(distinct r.id) + sum(ca.amount * ca.quantity) as net_sales
From
    trip_types tt
    inner Join reservation_trips rt on tt.id = rt.trip_type_id 
    inner Join reservations r on rt.reservation_id = r.id
    left outer join cost_adjustments ca on ca.reservation_trip_id = rt.id
    left outer join cost_types ct on ca.cost_type_id = ct.id
Where
    r.created_at >= '2013-01-01T09:00:00+00:00' and
    r.created_at < '2014-01-01T09:00:00+00:00' and
    rt.trip_type_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) and
    ca.trip_type_id in (5, 6, 7, 8) and
    contact_id in (9, 10, 11, 12) and
    ct.kind != 'tax'
Group By
    tt.title
```

Comment: Good catch on your question about commissions! I conferred with a friend and found a much more possible complex example that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl, I think it covers it

```
SELECT trip_types.title as trip_type_title,
COUNT(DISTINCT reservations.id) as bookings,
SUM(reservations.commissions) as commissions,  distinct reservations,
SUM(reservation_trips.id) as guests,  distinct reservation_trips,
SUM(reservation_trips.amount * reservation_trips.quantity) as gross_sales, 
SUM(cost_adjustments.amount * cost_adjustments.quantity) as adjustments,  distinct cost_adjustments where cost_types.kind != 'tax'
SUM(gross_sales + adjustments - commissions) as net_sales
FROM trip_types tt
JOIN reservation_trips on tt.id = reservation_trips.trip_type_id 
JOIN reservations on reservation_trips.reservation_id = reservations.id
JOIN cost_adjustments ON cost_adjustments.reservation_trip_id = reservation_trips.id
WHERE 
reservations.created_at >= '2013-01-01T09:00:00+00:00' AND
reservations.created_at < '2014-01-01T09:00:00+00:00' AND
reservation_trips.trip_type_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) AND
cost_adjustments.trip_type_id in (5, 6, 7, 8) AND
contact_id in (9, 10, 11, 12)
GROUP BY trip_types.title
```

Comment: I think the results need to be grouped by `trip_types.title`. Also what were comments in the specification are now merged into the SQL

Comment: you have `distinct reservations` twice. In the spec it was a comment `-- distinct reservations`. It's not the only example

Answer (score 0):

I conferred with a friend and figured it out. The trick that I didn't explain very well in the question (sorry) was that the search should include all trips and adjustments for reservations patching the search terms in my example where clause. So you have to use a 'with' query to first find the appropriate reservations, and then filter trips and adjustments based on that. Very tricky.

Here is the answer we found with slightly different fields actually used in production, but operate to the same effect:

```
    with reservations_search as (
    select
        distinct reservations.id
    from
        reservations
        left outer join contacts on
            reservations.contact_id = contacts.id
        left outer join reservation_trips on
            reservations.id = reservation_trips.reservation_id
        left outer join cost_adjustments on
            reservation_trips.id = cost_adjustments.cost_target_id
    where
        #{Reservation.warez_sql(params)[0].join(' AND ')}
    )

    select
        res_level.breeze_id,
        res_level.trip_category_id,
        res_level.bookings,
        res_level.commissions,
        res_level.guests,
        adjustments_level.adjustments,
        res_level.gross_sales + adjustments_level.adjustments - res_level.commissions as net_sales
    FROM
        (select
            breeze_id,
            trip_category_id,
            sum(trip_commission) as commissions,
            count(distinct reservation_id) as bookings,
            count(reservation_trip_id) as guests,
            sum(gross_sales) as gross_sales
        from

            -- Commissions by reservation_trips.id
            (select
                reservations.id as reservation_id,
                reservation_trips.id as reservation_trip_id,
                reservation_trips.amount * reservation_trips.quantity as gross_sales,
                case
                    when reservations.total_cost_commissionable > 0
                    then coalesce(reservations.commission, 0) * reservation_trips.total_cost_commissionable / reservations.total_cost_commissionable
                    else 0
                end as trip_commission,
                trip_types.breeze_id,
                trip_types.trip_category_id
            from
                reservations
                left outer join contacts on
                    reservations.contact_id = contacts.id
                left outer join reservation_trips on
                    reservations.id = reservation_trips.reservation_id
                left outer join trip_types on
                    reservation_trips.trip_type_id = trip_types.id
            where
                reservations.id in (select id from reservations_search) ) as trip_level
        group by
            breeze_id,
            trip_category_id) as res_level

        -- Adjustments
        left outer join
                (select
                    trip_types.breeze_id,
                    sum(cost_adjustments.amount * cost_adjustments.quantity) as adjustments
                 from
                    reservation_trips
                    left outer join reservations on
                        reservation_trips.reservation_id = reservations.id
                    left outer join cost_adjustments on
                        cost_target_type = 'ReservationTrip' and
                        reservation_trips.id=cost_adjustments.cost_target_id
                    left outer join cost_types on
                        cost_type_id = cost_types.id
                    left outer join trip_types on
                        reservation_trips.trip_type_id=trip_types.id
                 where
                    reservations.id in (select id from reservations_search) and
                    cost_types.commissionable IS TRUE
                 group by
                    trip_types.breeze_id) as adjustments_level on

             res_level.breeze_id = adjustments_level.breeze_id
```

Comment: Oh, and Laurence, regarding your question about commissions, my friend caught that as well and we decided to divide the commission among the trips according to their dollar value.